# UIWebView debugging JavaScript memory issue

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an application I'm working on where I've been provided with JavaScript code to implement within my webView. The following code below is what I use to load the localized JS code into the web view to render it on screen.

```
- (void)configureWebView {
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSString *directory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", self.model.name];

    NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:directory];

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], directory]]];
}
```

The JS is loaded locally, but after backing out of this viewController and re entering it (and even when staying in the viewController and navigating around the 3D render that the JavaScript provides), after a while the application will receive a memory warning and crash. The ViewController is deallocated and not retained after being left. The webView seems to be leaving a memory footprint and the JavaScript seems to be eating a ton of memory. I've attached screen shots for the Leaks took and such below. I'm unsure of what this means and am looking for anyone to help me debug the situation (confirming if it is a bug with UIWebView or the JavaScript). I've already setup a base line project with just a webView and the JavaScript code loaded in it, and I did receive memory warnings when hitting above 20mb in memory.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `self.webView.delegate = nil;` in `dealloc`.

Comment: Manually setting the web view to nil has already been tried along with manipulating cache policies and manually clearing hidden cache files.

Comment: What about `delegate`?

Comment: A delegate is always a weak reference. It's released when the web view is dealloc'ed

Comment: Are you sure? From the doc: Important: Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to nil. This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

Comment: Yes, the issue occurs when navigating around the JavaScript 3D generated view for a long period of time. Over time the memory skyrockets. I did find a retaining issue because a child vc was not being released/removed when poping the viewController though (this was holding onto the webView reference). I also noted what you just stated from the documentation. I find that extremely weird because of the way ARC works.